# How to add a download link to a video from WP media library?

Tags: videos

I wanted to have a link to allow the users to download the videos.
But a direct link to an `mp4` file opens a native player in some browsers (like Chrome and Safari) and plays the video instead of downloading it. So I'd have to put a note next to the link *“Right click and choose to save link as...”* to let the users know how to save it, and I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the download attribute.

Here is an example:

```
<a href="/media/my_new_song.mp3" download>click to download my song</a>
```

[Here is a W3Schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_download_link.asp) for further reference.